# Get Like Button Code: Like Button disappears

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ to get the code, every time I enter my website www.dealhijack.com the Like Button on the right disappears. If add to my website /deals  or anything then it works, but the root one dealhijack.com, the one that I want, does not work.

I do not understand why it does not like the website name. I could not find out why.

Any help in resolving it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a protocol. In short - just add 'http://' to the start.

Answer (score 0):

I've added http:// to your link, worked fine.

FB returned this code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.dealhijack.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```